# MVC 6 - RC1 to RC2 changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application that works fine on RC1 of ASP.NET MVC6. I heard that RC2 is going to use CLI instead of DNX command line tools.

Can somebody please tell me:

1. Will Project.json undergo any change (apart from package versions, of course)? Currently there is entry dnx451 and dnxcore50 under frameworks section. Will they change post RC2?
2. I know EF7 migrations commands are going to change but are there any code level changes?
3. Any other major code level change?

I can't use RC2 packages currently since this project is already in development. But trying to get a feel of what all I need to change when RC2 becomes available.

Comment: Here is a [`migration guide`](https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/)

Answer (score 9):

According to the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap), there shouldn't be any major changes:

> **RC1 - Stabilization**
>
> The focus for RC1 will be on polishing existing features, responding
>   to customer feedback and improving performance and reliability. The
>   goal is for RC1 to be a stable and production ready release.
>
> **RC2 - Move to .NET CLI**
>
> For RC2 we will move ASP.NET 5 to be based on the new cross-platform
>   .NET Core command line toolchain.

There is more details on the changes needed to migrate between the two on [Shawn Wildermuth's blog](http://wildermuth.com/2016/05/16/Converting-an-ASP-NET-Core-RC1-Project-to-RC2) and [David Pine's blog](https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/).

It mainly seems to be renamespacing from `Microsoft.AspNet.*` dependencies to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` ones

Comment: It's worth noting that project.json will die soon https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/4iveez/projectjson_is_dead_aspnet_core_goes_back_to/

Answer (score 2):

I believe there would be many code braking changes as ASP.NET 5 is already renamed to ASP.NET Core. So all the nuget packages version name is going to change and one will have to manually work and fix this. As there is no direct migration for now.

Coming back to your question

- Till RC 1, every ASP.NET Core project is a DNX project but that’s no
  more valid with RC2 release.
- In RC2, DNX is gone. It will be replaced via dotnet cli tool.
- Incremental compilation is back.
- The ASP.NET team has also moved away from dnx so in project.json dnx would be replaced by net.

Take a look at this - [What’s new in ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/whats-new-in-asp-net-5-rc-2-or-asp-net-core/)

And earlier this week, .NET team has released a sample RC2 project on github. It was also discussed in last [ASP.NET community stand up last week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkzeOqSNtwQ). You can also read [A First look at ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/first-look-asp-net-core-1-rc2-project/)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core RC2 availability [has been announced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/) recently.

Highlight changes from the announce:

- [ASP.NET 5 rebranded to ASP.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/02/01/an-update-on-asp-net-core-and-net-core/)
- [DNVM, DNX and DNU are replaced with CLI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-net-core-rc2)
- ASP.NET Core is now a console app rather than just a class library with a Startup class.
- IIS gets a module for hosting ASP.NET Core apps.

Resources on migrating from RC1 to RC2:

- [Migrating from DNX to .NET Core](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html)
- [Migrating from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to
  ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html)
- [Migrating your Entity Framework Code from RC1 to
  RC2](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html)

Additional resources:

- [Full list of changes in RC2](https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20milestone%3A1.0.0-rc2)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to NikilaiDante answer I believe your project.json has mentions of dnx and if you use migrations you have tooling called Ef Commands. Ef commands is being replaced and dnx is deprecated.

In the meantime, you could add support to dnx in rc2 (maybe) using 
services.AddMvcDnx();
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4187

Answer (score -1):

According to the newest information, RC2 should be available at mid-May 2016 and final at the end of June 2016: [NET Core RC2 – Improvements, Schedule, and Roadmap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/#comment-66365)

Comment: The essential parts are the release dates and included in the message.

Comment: Nothing in the Question asks about when this is changing, only what and some more things. So your answer is worthless without the link, which makes it link-only.